# How can I setting datasource in Spring application

Tags: mysql, spring, jakarta-ee

I have a simple application with `Spring-MVC` and `J2EE`. Now I want to config the datasource. I want use `my-SQL` and I don't want use hibernate. So I have write a java class (`visualizzazioni.java`) to connect at mysql database. So the name of database, username, password for now are static. I want to get this parameter from a config file. How can I configure mysql in spring???

This is the my `visualizzazioni.java`:

```
package com.springmvcapp.manager;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import com.springmvcapp.utility.Propr;

public class Visualizzazioni extends JPanel{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String nomeDB;       // Nome del Database a cui connettersi
    private String nomeUtente;   // Nome utentStringe utilizzato per la connessione al Database
    private String pwdUtente;    // Password usata per la connessione al Database
    private String errore;       // Raccoglie informazioni riguardo l'ultima eccezione sollevata
    private String host;
    public static Connection db;       // La connessione col Database
    private boolean connesso;    // Flag che indica se la connessione è attiva o meno
    public Properties properties=null;
    public Visualizzazioni() { 

        this.nomeDB= "spring_mvc";
        this.pwdUtente="password";
        this.nomeUtente="root";
        this.host= "localhost";

        connesso = false;
        errore = "";
    }

    // Apre la connessione con il Database
    public boolean connetti() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException{
        connesso = false;
        //log = new MyLog4J();
        try {
            // Carico il driver JDBC per la connessione con il database MySQL
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            // Controllo che il nome del Database non sia nulla
            if (!nomeDB.equals("")) {
                //192.168.1.157
                this.pwdUtente="password";//properties.getProperty("root");
                this.nomeUtente="root";//properties.getProperty("user");

                //InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
                //DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:mysql/jdbc/spring_mvc");


                db = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+ host +"/" + nomeDB + "?user=" + nomeUtente + "&password=" + pwdUtente);
                connesso = true;
            } else {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            //log.logStackTrace(e);
        }
        return connesso;
    }

    public static Connection getDb() {
        return db;
    }

    public static void setDb(Connection db) {
        Visualizzazioni.db = db;
    }

    public boolean isConnesso() { return connesso; }   // Ritorna TRUE se la connessione con il Database è attiva
    public String getErrore() { return errore; }       // Ritorna il messaggio d'errore dell'ultima eccezione sollevata
}
```

Comment: do you want to pick up these values from spring config file or properties file?

Comment: I want get this file from properties file, because my idea is, when I try to start this project in another server, I can change the name of the database, password etc, then start the TomCat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get values from property file you need to do it like this

```
ResourceBundle sqlConnectionFileResource = ResourceBundle.getBundle("configFile");
String value=sqlConnectionFileResource.getString("propertyName");
```

where the file from which you want to pick up values is `configFile.properties` having entries in format

```
propertyName=propertyValue
```

remember to give only file name in getBundle method i.e. use only `ResourceBundle.getBundle("configFile");`

instead of

`ResourceBundle.getBundle("configFile.properties");`

hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: Where I can put this config file?

Comment: I have this situation in my project.
http://it.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=abia2p&s=8#.VOWmFC5K0XE

Where is the resources folder?

Comment: make a new resource folder in it(at same level as build,config etc).and provide correct path while you load the bundle, so that java can find it

Comment: I have create a new folder under activites,build and config folder. The name of the folder is "resource". In this folder I have insert configFile.properties. So when I try to use your code, I have an error:

this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load resource/configFile.properties.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71238/discussion-between-bircastri-and-vihar).