# Accessing properties in Mule flow

Tags: java, properties, mule

How can we access loaded properties, which are loaded at Mule bootstrap, pro- grammatically from a Java class? To be more clear:

My Mule application will load **some.properties** file at bootstrap and will use these using the placeholder ${} inside a flow. My question is How can we access these loaded properties inside a Java class pro-grammatically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the property-placeholder set up in your mule-config.xml? E.g. is it `constretto:configuration` ?

Comment: Using this: <context:property-placeholder location="some.properties"/>

Comment: is this property file present in your project itself, or it is loaded from external source?

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28601590/how-can-i-setting-datasource-in-spring-application/28601854#28601854

Comment: I don't want the properties to be loaded again; instead, I want to used already loaded properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no point on reading them programatically as you can get them [injected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317687/how-can-i-inject-a-property-value-into-a-spring-bean-which-was-configured-using).

If you really want to, from the mule context, get the mule registry and from there just [get the object](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Storing+Objects+in+the+Registry).

Comment: How can I access those injected properties inside a Java class?